# How to convert a 2D array into a single string in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, path-finding

Am writing a pathfinder and have a 21x21 array which I want to convert into a single string. The array will contain only 1's and 0's. The 1's are placed together in order to form the path.

My current relevant code snippet is

```
std::string str;

for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
    {
        str += grid[i][j];
    }
}

std::cout << str;
return (str);
```

When I run the code it jumps to a file containing
`static inline size_t length(const char_type* __s) {return strlen(__s);}` and says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Can you make this a complete example so we can try it?

Comment: you are going to far in your loop i < 20  not 21 same for j, arrays are 0 based indexing, so a 20 by 20 array will have indexes from 0-19 not 0-20

Comment: If you have 20x20 array make the `for`-s <20 not 21 because it will try to acces `grid[20][20] ` and your indexes should be 0 to 19.

Comment: what is `type` of `grid[i][j]`?

Comment: configured the grid a but weirdly so is actually a 21x21 grid. Sorry for the confusion! Any other ideas? The code is quite long!

Comment: this is how i initialised the grid - int grid[21][21] = {};

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code in your loop

```
str +=std::to_string(grid[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are attempting to access index 20 which isn't available, because you have started the loop from 0.

You can  change the iteration limits from 0 to 20.

Comment: Why `1 to 20` ?

Comment: my bad, bit sleepy

Answer (score 0):

Your array is 20x20, so from index 0 to 19. 
Your for loops are checking from index 0 to 20. 
index [20] doesn't exist.
Change "`i < 21`" in your for loop to : `i < 20`. Same for J.

Answer (score 0):

`grid[i][0]` is acting a char pointer that has only been allocated 20 bytes of space, so the `+=` operation is protecting you from grabbing garbage data that lies beyond that last byte.

Answer (score -1):

You are iterating too far in you grid. your loops should be:

```
    std::string str;

    // iterate through i index from 0 to 19. 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // iterate through j index from 0 to 19.
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 20 ; j++)
        {
            // After testing it you do need to replace str += a[i][j]; for it to do what you want. 
            str.append(std::to_string(grid[i][j])); 
        }
    }
    std::cout << str;
    return(str);
```

After your correction about how grid was initialized I wrote a test to see if I could get your issue I could not. However without the append(to_string) change it would not produce the string you would expect. It interprets the int as a char and puts a character who's ASCII numeric value is 0 or 1. instead of using the '0' or '1' characters who's numeric ASCII code values are 48 and 49.

This was my complete test program: compiled with "g++ -std=c++11 " on a Ubuntu VM.

```
 #include<iostream>

 int main()
 {
    int a[21][21] = {}; 

    a[1][1]=1;
    a[2][1]=1;

    std::string str;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 21; ++i)
    {   
       for (int j = 0; j < 21; ++j)
       {   
          str.append(std::to_string(a[i][j]));
       }   
    }   

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
 }
```

The output:

```
 000000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: i configured it weirdly so the 21 should be fine, I think. Could you explain a bit further what you mean by your suggestion?

Comment: If you grid type is char for example it will not interpret a value of "1" or "0" the way you think. If grid type is int or short it should be ok.

Comment: grid type is int. So its a 21x21 grid and the loop is fine.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are accessing something out of bounds.

Comment: ah okay, thanks! So if I use str.append(std::to_string(grid[i][j])); should it work?

Comment: Not sure, but it should not hurt to try. I do not have a means to really test it at the moment. If you are accessing data out of bounds in grid then no it will not help.

Comment: May I also suggest running in gdb or a debugger that way you can see when/why it is blowing up on you :).

Comment: @GeorgePerkins Just wrote a test and without the append and to_string it did not do what you would expect, with it it works. So yes